# can we replicate Cross Region Replication (CRR) across more than 2 regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database-replication

Cross Region Replication is one of the 2017 updates for DynamoDB.To experience with it, I used AWS Management Console to replicate my database once. Just wondered if anybody knows how to replicate it across more than 2 regions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for Global Tables.  Not all regions are supported, but this gives you read/write access to the same table across multiple (more than 2) regions.

> Global Tables replicates your Amazon DynamoDB tables automatically across your choice of AWS regions.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/global-tables/